# How to "Export saved data and transmit that data to a new activity in Android"

Tags: android, sqlite

I saved the SQLite data in android; But when I call the data out to transfer it to another activity, it only transmits the last data in the database via another activity. where do i need to set the encoding? Thanks.

This is a Android Studio 3.0 and SQLite. In the past, I've tried on 
Exporting saved data in SQLite database and transfering that data to a new activity. I always only have the last data in my database.

---

### **My code in Main Activity**

```
 private void xuLyXemLuotLike(View view) {
        database = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor cursor = database.query("ArirangSongList", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        //dsBaiHatGoc.clear();
        int soLike = 0;
        int soDislike = 0;
        String mabh ="";
        String tenbh = "";
        String casi = "";
        Music music = new Music();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            mabh = cursor.getString(0);
            tenbh = cursor.getString(1);
            casi = cursor.getString(3);
            soLike = cursor.getInt(6);
            soDislike = cursor.getInt(7);
            music.setMa(mabh);
            music.setTen(tenbh);
            music.setCaSi(casi);
            music.setSoLike(soLike);
            music.setSoDislike(soDislike);
          //  dsBaiHatGoc.add(music);
        }
        cursor.close();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, XemLuotLikeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mabh",mabh);
            intent.putExtra("tenbh", tenbh);
            intent.putExtra("casi", casi);
            intent.putExtra("soLike", soLike);
            intent.putExtra("soDislike", soDislike);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

---

### **My code in another Activity:**

```
    txtKetQua= (TextView) this.<View>findViewById(R.id.txtKetQua);
    Intent intent =getIntent();

    String mabh =intent.getStringExtra("mabh");

    String tenbh =intent.getStringExtra("tenbh");
    String casi =intent.getStringExtra("casi");

    int soLike =intent.getIntExtra("soLike", 0);
    int soDislike =intent.getIntExtra("soDislike",0);

    txtKetQua.setText(mabh + "   " + tenbh + "   " + casi + "   " + soLike+ "   " + soDislike);
```

---

[My code in Another Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90V0n.jpg)

[My code in Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWXBN.jpg)

Comment: Create a list e.g. `ArrayList<Music>` fill it inside your `while` loop.

Comment: Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Each time a row is accessed it uses the same variable, so the values are overwritten and thus only the last row is used to set the values passed via the intent.

Unless you want many intents (e.g. append to position to the key name) then it would be better to retrieve the data, from the database, in the other activity.

You could send many intentExtras (a set per row) along with a counter of the number of rows using somthing like :-

```
private void xuLyXemLuotLike(View view) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor cursor = database.query("ArirangSongList", null, null, null, null, null, null);

    //dsBaiHatGoc.clear();
    int soLike = 0;
    int soDislike = 0;
    String mabh ="";
    String tenbh = "";
    String casi = "";
    Music music = new Music();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, XemLuotLikeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("rowcounter",cursor.getCount()); //<<<<<<<<<< number of rows
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        intent.putExtra("mabh"+String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition()),cursor.getString(0));
        intent.putExtra("tenbh"+String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition()),cursor.getString(1));
        intent.putExtra("casi"+String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition()),cursor.getString(3));
        intent.putExtra("soLike"+String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition()),cursor.getInt(6));
        intent.putExtra("soDislke"+String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition()),cursor.getInt(7));
    }
    cursor.close();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

- this will send intentExtras with keys mabh0 mabh1 mabh2 ........

You could then retrieve the data using something like :-

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int rowcounter = intent.getIntExtra("rowcounter",-1);

    Music[] allthemusicpass = new Music[rowcounter];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowcounter; i++) {
        allthemusicpass[i].setMa(intent.getStringExtra("mabh"+String.valueOf(i)));
        allthemusicpass[i].setTen(intent.getStringExtra("tenbh"+String.valueOf(i)));
        allthemusicpass.setCaSi(intent.getStringExtra("casi"+String.valueOf(i)));
        allthemusicpass.setSoLike(intent.getIntExtra("soLike"+String.valueOf(i),-1));
        allthemusicpass.setSoDislike(intent.getIntExtra("soDislike"+String.valueOf(i),-1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    ArrayList<Music> musicList = new ArrayList<Music>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

       // first add implements Serializable to Music class
       // make constructor with respective parameters
         Music music = new Music(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7));

        musicList.add(music);
    }
    cursor.close();

   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, XemLuotLikeActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("musicList",musicList);            
   startActivity(intent);
```

then in XemLuotLikeActivity Activity oncreate()

```
ArrayList<Music> musiclist = (ArrayList<Music>) intent.getSerializable("musicList");

or
musiclist = (ArrayList<Music>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("musicList");
```